# How to perform multiple Nightmare functions asynchronously

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, nightmare

I'm scraping a webpage with Nightmare , and would like to know how to reuse a function over over array of inputs.

Lets say i have a method to retrieve title of a page

```
function* test(url,callback) {
    var size = { width: 1920, height: 1080, 'use-content-size': true, show: true }

    var nightmare = Nightmare(size)
    var title = yield nightmare
    .goto('http://cnn.com')
    .evaluate(function () {
        return document.title
    });
    console.log(title)
    yield nightmare.end()
    callback()
}
```

I would like to perform this method over a array of urls. So i am using async library in order to run all over the array and perform the `test` function over `urls` array of urls.

```
async.each(urls, test, function (err) {
    console.log('done!');
});
```

But `async.each` has no support for generators functions , How can i change the test function to a normal function instead of a generator function.

Comment: What happens when you run the code? You should also use url instead of http://cnn.com in the goto function.

Comment: Did you got any way out?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to do it - I need to use a promises library in order to perform multiple functions , and it is a normal function.

```
function test(url){
    Promise.resolve(  // call for the promises library with the nightmare instance 
        nightmare
        .goto() //all the calls that you need
        .wait()
        .....    
        ).then(function (result) { //This function will be called when the block of commands is done , with the result.
              console.log("Done")
        }, function (err) { //Error handling 
              console.log(err);
    });
}
```